# How could I change state on Server Actions in NextJS 13?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-state, next.js13

##### I have been trying to solve an issue regarding Server Actions on NextJS 13.

I am interested in changing state during the execution of a server action. Here, I have an `actions.ts` file on the root of the `app` directory. For now, I have a whole page as a client component for the sake of the question (I will implement this on its own client component in the future). Anyhow, I would like to change the state called `someState` to `true` inside the server action called `myAction` once the form is submitted.

##### Here is the code:

```
//page.tsx
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { myAction } from '../actions'

export default function Test() {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
      <form action={myAction}>
        <button type="submit">Test</button>
      </form>

      {someState && <p>someState is true</p>}
      {!someState && <p>someState is false</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
//actions.ts
'use server'

export async function myAction() {
  console.log('Running action on server')
}
```

I have spent several days trying to find a solution for this; alas, I am here asking. I appreciate any help granted. If you read this, thank you.

##### What I tried

I tried passing the `setSomeState` function as a parameter for `myAction`. NextJS 13 did not like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  [experimental useOptimistic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions) is used for this.

> When a Server Action is invoked, the UI is updated immediately to
> reflect the expected outcome, instead of waiting for the Server
> Action's response.

```
 const [optimisticValue, addOptimisticValue] = useOptimistic(
    initialValue,
    // depends how you want to manipulate the state
    (state, newValue) => [...state, { newValue:newValue }]
  )

 return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
      <form action={async () => {
                         await myAction()
                         addOptimisticValue("test value")
                    }}>
        <button type="submit">Test</button>
      </form>

      {someState && <p>someState is true</p>}
      {!someState && <p>someState is false</p>}
    </div>
  )
```